# not working link in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap dropdown and below is the code
The issue is when I click dropdown link it is not working in mobile device but it is working well on desktop (tested on chrome browser + Mozilla)

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="images/report.png"> </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu text-uppercase">
         <li><a href="02.02.01.01.group-option-select-supplier-group-base.html">Select supplier </a></li>
         <li><a href="02.02.02.01.report-option-Inventory.html">inventory </a></li>
         <li><a href="02.02.03.01.report-option-purchse.html">Purchase </a></li>
         <li><a href="02.02.04.01.group-option-select-report-group-base.html">Select report </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuEpG.png)

Comment: use this one you can do with more it.https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel I think he want to say that he is using bootstrap code and in android / I phone device it is not working